# Force non secure cookie in SSL enabled Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, cookies

I have a Rails 4 app that has `config.force_ssl = true` enabled in production, however I need to set a specific unsecured cookie. I have tried passing `secure: false` in the cookie options as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way of doing this?